# OpenVPNServiceInteractive is not started. Tasks requiring administrative access may not work

Tags: openvpn, services

On bootup, I get an OpenVPN dialog that says:

> "OpenVPNServiceInteractive" is not started. Tasks requiring administrative access may not work.

[image: OpenVPNServiceInteractive not started dialog]

If I disregard the message and try to connect to my VPN anyway, I will get another error later on when OpenVPN tries to setup the routing table.

If I quit open VPN, wait a while (a few minutes), and then try again, I no longer get the error dialog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the OpenVPNInteractiveService is set to startup Automatic (Delayed). To resolve this:

1. Open Services
2. Open 'OpenVPN Interactive Service'
3. Change the *Startup type:* to *Automatic*.

[image: Services List]

The service incorrectly set to delayed automatic start:

[image: Delayed Start]

The service corrected to automatic (non-delayed) start:

[image: Automatic Start]

### More Information

[OpenVPN developers said to make sure the service is set to Automatic](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn-gui/issues/111#issuecomment-270004876):

> Also, as installed, the service start type is auto, make sure it has not been changed to delayed-auto.

[OpenVPNInteractiveService is](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPNInteractiveService):

> ... a Windows system service which allows unprivileged openvpn.exe process to do certain privileged operations, such as adding routes.

From Windows Internals, 6th Edition page 327:

> After handling auto-start services, the SCM calls ScInitDelayStart, which queues a delayed work item associated with a worker thread responsible for processing all the services that ScAutoStartServices skipped because they were marked delayed auto-start. This worker thread will execute after the delay. **The default delay is 120 seconds**, but can be overridden by the [sic] creating an AutoStartDelay value in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control.

Comment: I had this error and I can confirm that this fix helped.

Comment: Also, don't forget to actually start the service, if it is not running currently.

Comment: I have this problem in Windows 7. But OpenVPN Interactive Service is already set to Startup Type=Automatic. Nevertheless I still got that error anyway... "OpenVPNServiceInteractive is Not started". But by the time I check in Windows Services its status is "started". I guess it's not starting quickly enough?